# T-SQL code for restoring a database doesn't work inside a Delphi query, but it works in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, delphi, devart

I am trying to restore a database which I use in a Delphi program.

When I try to do the restore, it doesn't show any errors and the T-SQL code passes, but there is no change in the database that I am trying to restore to a previous state. On the other hand, if I run the same code in SSMS 18, it works as expected.

Here is the code in Delphi:

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master RESTORE DATABASE [' + DBName +
  '] FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
  ' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 1 USE [' + DBName + ']';
```

Here is the SQL value inside the query before it's execution:

```
USE master RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] 
FROM DISK = ''RestorePath'' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 1 USE [DBName]'#$D#$A
```

For `DBName` and `RestorePath`, I pass the correct values, but I thought it's not relevant, so I changed it in the example here to `DBName` and `RestorePath`, since they were very long and made the code hard to read (especially the `RestorePath`). I did the same with the next block of code.

Finally, here is the code that works in SSMS:

```
USE master 

RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] FROM DISK = 'RestorePath'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 1 

USE [DBName]
```

I don't know if this is relevant but the restore is being done in a different thread and a backup works fine. So, can anybody help me find out why does it work in SSMS and it doesn't with the Delphi code and how to make the restore with Delphi in a way that it works?

Since a comment asked here is more info about how I execute it. I create a query and a connection. I don't think that the problem is in the values I give to them, since I do the same with the backup and it works, so I'm not going to copy and paste the values, just the way I use the query. After I create it and give it the needed values(just like with the connection and data source) I give the query the SQL code like this

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master RESTORE DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
      ' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 1 USE [' + DBName + ']';
```

and then execute it like this:

```
Query.Execute;
```

After that I free the connection, query and datasource.

Comment: How do you execute this code with Delphi?

Comment: For starters, the Delphi code is wrong. It's not the same as the one you used in SSMS. `USE` and `RESTORE` are different commands but the Delphi code put them in the same line. If you really want them in the same line, use `;` as the separator. Second, you don't need USE at all. The restore operation is performed by the `RESTORE` command, not the `USE`

Comment: @zhorov I added more context for what you asked

Comment: Either add `;` or  a newline between the commands or remove `USE` altogether.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what you suggested didn't work. Also, I don't see what's the problem with the "use" statement, since it's completely different from the restore. I used "USE master" not to make restore but to make sure that the query doesn't use the database it tries to restore, since that also results in a problem. You said to add ";" which is something I hadn't tried, but I don't understand what would that change? Do you mean that I use one Query execution to make the "use" statement and another to make the restore?

Comment: The database is specified in the connection string. `didn't work`. What didn't work? Did you get an error? Are you connecting to the *correct* server in the first place? Are you checking for errors? I can see more problems in the query content, eg `DISK = ''RestorePath''` that's two quotes instead of one. What is `QuotedStr` and why is it used? Are you sure the problem isn't the content of `RestorePath` ? Quotes aren't valid in file paths. If `RestorePath` is surrounded by quotes already, double-quoting will only cause problems *and* possibly result in SQL injections.

Comment: The semicolon is a statement terminator. It is missing in your delphi code. SSMS is pretty smart about ending statements when it encounters a newline (like what you posted from SSMS).

Comment: The string `'#$D#$A` at the end of the query means that somehow, the generated string contained newlines that got converted. Please post the *actual, full* code you used, not just disjointed snippets. Include the code that stores the value in `RestorePath` too, and any error handling code

Comment: Also the RESTORE command generates a bunch of messages, which the client must consume.  Otherwise the client may be aborting the RESTORE unintentionally.  See, eg in Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838573/pyodbc-sql-server-database-restore-incomplete/61839547#61839547

Comment: Did you got an error ? What did it say ?

Comment: You can pass the DISK path as a parameter, eg `DISK = @path_param` or `DISK = ?`. This way there's no need to quote anything and you avoid SQL injection issues completely. No amount of quoting can protect from SQL injection problems.

Comment: @Ineffable21, what components do you use to connect to SQL Server and execute the query?

Comment: @GuidoG no error

Comment: @zhorov TMSConnection, TMSDataSource, TMSQuery

Comment: If you get no error, than what is not working ?

Comment: So you're using DevArt's drivers. Why are you using TMSQuery at all? You aren't querying anything. RESTORE doesn't return any results. To execute a command use `TMSConnection.ExecSQL`. If you search for `Delphi SQL Server Restore` you'll find lots of answers that use `ExecSQL`. The Query class is only for queryinng

Comment: @GuidoG the restore isn't happening. When I do it in SSMS the tables go back to the way they were when I made the backup, when I do it with Delphi the tables stay the way they were changed after the backup

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not because of what I am executing. When I execute the backup it works fine. I tried Connection.ExecSQL and it didn't change anything.

Comment: DevArt's libraries are pretty complete and it *definitely* has a TDADump class that handles backups and restores. Have you tried using the built-in classes instead of trying on your own?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, I haven't tried doing that. I didn't know there were such classes. Can you suggest a way to use them or a documentation where I could read about them?

Comment: @Ineffable21 if you execute what you posted, you're specifying an empty path. `''` is an empty string. Anything that follows is raw text in the command itself. `TMSQuery` is *only* for queries, and RESTORE doesn't return any results.

Comment: When the restore is not happening then there must be an error/reason, which will be returned but you probably do not catch this in the delphi client. My guess is there is a reason returned to your delphi client but you don't see it and therefor don't know of it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried using parameter and it didn't work. What you are saying about the empty path is wrong, since it definitely works with the backup. I think my problem is that the query doesn't have enough time to execute, before I free it.

Comment: It definitely doesn't. If I paste `RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] 
FROM DISK = ''RestorePath'' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 1` in SSMS I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.` and `RestorePath` is highlighted as an error. Either nobody else knows how backups work, or your code is wrong

Comment: If I paste `USE master RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] FROM DISK = ''RestorePath'' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 1 USE [DBName]'#$D#$A` both `RestorePath` is highlighted as an error **and** `'#$D#$A`. Notice that single quote at the end - that's *exactly* how SQL injection attacks happen. Imagine what would happen if, wherever that `'\r\n` came from contained `; DROP Table Students;--` instead. Or `' OR 1=1; DROP Table Students; --`

Comment: Please stop the discussion in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question to add the relevant details there, where they can be seen as part of the question, instead of burying them in all this noise and clutter. When a comment thread gets to be more than a few posts, it's an indication that either the question is missing vital details or that the conversation has gone off the rails. In this case, it may be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to make it work. After I added **Synchronize()** and called a method, with which I refresh the grids I use to show the data from the database, at the end of the TThread(after I free the connection and query) it worked correctly. Here is the final outcome:

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName + ']' + 
      ' SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ' + 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
      ' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 1 ' +
      'ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName + '] SET ONLINE ' + 'USE [' + DBName + ']';

Query.Execute;

DataSource.Free;
Query.Free;
Connection.Free;

Synchronize(frmMain.MultiRefresh);
```

I used to call that function (frmMain.MultiRefresh) right after I executed the query without using Synchronize. After I used Synchronize to call the function the restore worked but it gave me an error that said "failed attempt to login in using user" or something like that. I think that happened because I was still using the database with the credentials in the query and the connection, so after I moved the Synchronize right after I freed the connection, query and dataSource, it worked well.

Comment: Now I get a different error: "An Existing Connection Was Forcibly Closed by the Remote Host", but that has nothing to do with the initial question I asked and seems to be more about the way I use the queries which I am going to try to figure it out or maybe ask another question in the future. That error doesn't stop the program or restore either, it just appears as a pop up